# Erro al clonar un proyecto de Git Hub en Visual Studio 20222

Tags: c#, visual-studio, github

Al tratar de clonar un proyecto cualquier proyecto de Git Hub
en Visual Studio 2022 me sale el siguiente error

Error setting certificate file:c:/program file/Git/mingw64/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además, haz el que el título de la pregunta también sea descriptivo.

Answer (score 0):

La manera de la que lo pudo solucionar fue:

1. **borrar la carpeta de Git** que esta en la ruta `c:/Archivo de Programas`
2. se intenta volver a clonar y ya funciona

Comment: Basicamente borraste el certificado en tu pc....